# can I change background image of Barcode Scanner viewfinder?

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

In my app, I managed to send intent to Barcode Scanner app and get result.

My problem is: After sent intent, Barcode Scanner activates and shows rectangle view finder in center and message "Place a barcode inside the viewfinder rectangle to scan it.". At this stage, I want to show custom background image which has some pictures around remaining center rectangle area transparent for view finder. Has anyone accomplished this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send an Intent to open another app, but you cannot do something like change the layout of the other app you open. It's not possible, sorry. Not unless that other app was built to accept intents from other apps and use the data attached in some way. For example, you could use `intent.putExtra()` to add your image or a reference id for it, but the the other app would have to be pre-built to do something with that data. And that would be up to the author of the other app.